# How to declare constant of some inductive type in Coq?

Tags: logic, coq

I am following https://github.com/brunofx86/LL/blob/master/FOLL/LL/SyntaxLL.v and there the inductive type is defined (parametrized Higher Order Abstract Syntax - PHOAS is used here):

```
(** Closed Terms *)
  Inductive ClosedT : Term -> Prop :=
  | cl_cte: forall C, ClosedT (Cte C)
  | cl_fc1: forall n t1, ClosedT t1 -> ClosedT (FC1 n t1)
  | cl_fc2: forall n t1 t2, ClosedT t1 -> ClosedT t2 -> ClosedT (FC2 n t1 t2).
```

My question is - how can I define constant `John` to be of type `ClosedT` using constructor `cl_cte`?

And additional question: there can be situations when I would like to define more types, e.g. `John : Person` and `Bruno : Tortoise` so - should I created new type, e.g. `ClosedT_Tortoise` for the new type? `ClosedT` is the base type upon which the object logic is built, so, maybe I should not proceed with multisort logic?

As I understand, then this formalization of the Linear Logic which I am using, is applied in the another Coq project http://subsell.logic.at/bio-CTC/ and it may be possible that the constants are defined there. But skimming source I can not find them.

Answer (score 3):

Strictly speaking, your question is ill-stated: `ClosedT` is not a type, but a family of propositions indexed by elements of the type `Term`.  Based on the file, I imagine that `ClosedT t` means that the term `t : Term` is closed, and that you want to do the following:

- Define a type of constants `T` that has an element `John : T`.
- Instantiate the definitions of the development with `T`.  For this, you need to wrap `T` in a module of type `Eqset_dec_pol` along with a proof that `T` has decidable equality, and apply the functor `Syntax_LL` that appears at the beginning of the file to this module.
- Embed `John` in the syntax of terms using the `Cte` "constructor" of `Term`. (This is not a constructor in the proper Coq sense of the word, but just a handy wrapper to build elements of type `Term`.)
- Prove that this term is closed; that is, prove `ClosedT (Cte John)`. This should just be a matter of applying the constructor `cl_cte`.

Is this more-or-less along the lines of what you want to do?